# read text from div that only has multiple class matches with Watir

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, watir

I am trying to read the text of a div that nested inside another. Each of these div's only have class as an identifier. I am tried to use the index of the div's but is not working at all. My html looks like this

```
<div class="zoneA">
 <div class="zone2A">
  <div class="zone3A">
   <div class="zone3ALeft">
     Text1
   </div
   <div class="zone3ARight">
     Text2
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="zoneA">
 <div class="zone2A">
  <div class="zone3A">
   <div class="zone3ALeft">
     Text3
   </div
   <div class="zone3ARight">
     Text4
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to read the text from the div's with class="zone3ARight", or Text2 and Text4.

I'm just not 100% sure on the way to do with with so many class's with the same name. I'm trying something like this.

```
puts browser.div(:class, "zone3ARight", :index, 0).text
puts browser.div(:class, "zone3ARight", :index, 1).text
```

But get argumentError: expected Hash or (:how, "what")

Comment: some of the end div tags are missings their >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to locate an element using multiple properties, they have to be supplied as a hash. A hash would look like:

```
:key1 => "value1", :key2=> "value2"
```

Notice that the key (ie how Watir should locate the element) and value (ie the what Watir should look for) are separated by a `=>` instead of a `,`.

Your code should be:

```
puts browser.div(:class => "zone3ARight", :index => 0).text
#=> "Text2"
puts browser.div(:class => "zone3ARight", :index => 1).text
#=> "Text4"
```

Note that you can also create a collection of all matching div elements and then iterate through each of them. This is useful if you want to go through all matching divs without knowing how many there are.

```
browser.divs(:class => "zone3ARight").each do |div|
    puts div.text
end
```

Note that `divs` is used instead of `div`.